# How do I get latest pdf file by given code using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried the following code to download all pdf file from the links but with that It download all files when I run these code every time. Recommended: First time it should download all pdf, and from next time it should download only which one is new.(it should check first which one is new)
My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_url = 'https://www.iea.org'

def getLinks(url):
    all_links = []
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
        all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))
    return all_links
yearLinks = getLinks(root_url +'/oilmarketreport/reports/')
# get report URL
reportLinks = []
for url in yearLinks:
    links = getLinks(url)
    #reportLinks.extend(links)

#print(reportLinks)
i =0
for url_ in links:
    if "AnnualStatisticalSupplement" not in url_:
        url__ = url_.replace("org..", "org").replace("../", "")
        response = requests.get(url__, stream=True)
        lastindex= url__.rfind('/')
        strlen = len(url__)
        filename = url__[lastindex:strlen]
        with open('/home/pdfs/'+ str(filename), 'wb') as pdffile:
            pdffile.write(response.content)
            i += 1
            print(url__)

print("Download Completed")
```

Then I need to store that file is Mongo DB, How should i do that by making three column(pdf name, reported date, flag of process).

Comment: Is there any solution for the question. actually I referred lots of tutorial but can't get the solution

Comment: are you trying to insert pdf name or content?

Comment: Can't you just scrape the pdf file link then use `import wget` to download the file from that link?

Comment: I already saved that files but my question is How do I get latest pdf file by given code using python

Comment: If i did not misunderstand what you describe that you only need to compare the date of them

Comment: @kcorlidy, I already download files from the link(by using above code)Now, want to get pdf which upload recently(other than downloaded) from links and store in mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the significant change in your code. because your code is too messy to read.
if you want to download the pdf you don't have since some time, you must add `if-loop` to control your action. by the way if you add page url into your database that you need not to access one more time to get the pdf name.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_url = 'https://www.iea.org'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}

downloaded = ["2018-02-13.pdf"] # the latest i have

def getLinks(url):
    page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    li = soup.find_all("li",class_="omrlist")
    links =  [root_url + href.a.get('href') for href in li]
    return links

def get_pdf(url,flag=1):
    # find page link in the month directory

    pdf_page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pdf_page.text, 'lxml')
    li = soup.find_all("li",class_="omrlist")[::-1] # latest -> old
    latest_pdf_set = [root_url + href.a.get('href')  for href in li]

    # find pdf link
    pdf_links = []
    for pdf_url in latest_pdf_set:
        text = requests.get(pdf_url,headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
        link = soup.find("div",class_="omrreport pL10").find("a").get("href")
        if link.split("/")[-1] in downloaded:
            flag = 0 # if flag = 0 means you found the pdf that you already had
            break
        pdf_links.append(root_url + link)

    return pdf_links,flag

yearLinks = getLinks(root_url +'/oilmarketreport/reports/')

all_ = []

for each in yearLinks:
    pdf_links = get_pdf(each)
    all_ += pdf_links[0]
    if not pdf_links[1]:
        # flag = 0 break 
        break

print(all_)
```